# ios How to move pins in the map view?

Tags: ios6, mapkit

Recently I started working on a project which is related to Maps. The flow my application is, I would like to show  moment of my friends on the map. I have a back end server and it has accurate information about the current position of those individuals. So, I Can get the information of their lats&longs from my server. But only problem is how can I show their moment on the maps like my Current location pin pointer does? When I am refreshing map with updated locations the pins should move to the new location. Can you guys help me how can I move different pins to different locations at the same time???

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, its very useful:

```
// Map view view annotation delegate method
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:
(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation)
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
        pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[_ex_map_view dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                          initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        [pinView setDraggable:YES];
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
    }
    return pinView;
}
```